# Using other elements in input instead of text

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to create input which will have editable span element. The ideas is to wrap input with relatively positioned div and then put another absolutely positioned div on top of input with span element in it. When span element is focused I want to listen to key down events and update span text concatenating it with key value (there will be multiple separate spans with different behavior).

The input itself is read only. I want to keep focus state and styling of it to make impression to the user than he focuses input when focusing or clicking on span element.

I have to focus input explicitly as when clicking on span. However when input focused span loses focus and I can't listen for key down events. Of course I can save state of last focused span and listen key down events on input and update span text accordingly. Other solution I though is simply applying some class with focus styling on input whenever span is clicked/focused.

Am I missing something fundamentally or there is no other options than using javascript and explicit targeting and styling of input on span events?

[CodeSandBox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-snowflake-ytzh9s)

**Edit**: I am trying to achieve something similar like Material UI is develiping in their new Date Reange Single Field [Single Date Range Field](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-range-field/). I already have styled input in my project so I am trying to use my project input fields and have some interactive spans inside that input instead of text.

Comment: Contenteditable?

Comment: As comment above stated, seems like you are reinventing the wheel for content editable element. Maybe it is not exactly the same thing. I am not sure how a read only input is getting events.

Comment: I am using text from react state in span and putting contenteditable on span allows me to listen to onInput event where event.nativeEvent.data is last type character which I set as a state. Problem is react does not re-render span value if value didn't change (for example if state value is letter "a" and I type "a" and set state to "a" again, react does not re-render but span innerText changed to "aa" and so on). This is hard to manage and it is mix up of react and vanilla js. I am trying to find solution without user allowing to change DOM and manage DOM through react.